# How to change Xcode Playground's to particular Swift Version?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcplayground

I tried a swift code that's working well in the playground but not in Xcode project. So I want to know how to change a Playground's particular swift version.

Answer (score 6):

sorry but you can't apple documentation says playground only run on latest swift version on your xcode

> Note: Swift Playgrounds 2.2 uses Swift 4.2 (swiftlang-1000.0.37.1).
>   Code written using other versions of Swift may not work in Swift
>   Playgrounds 2.2.

for more read [this](https://developer.apple.com/swift-playgrounds/release-notes/)

Comment: kindly share the apple documentaion link. it will be helpful.

Comment: you can read in updated answer sorry for not including that in first place